# How to prevent EF core 5 from creating a savepoint when saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

We're using EF Core within a context where we always manage the transaction externally. We also have to use MARS. This combination causes the following warning since we've upgraded to EF Core 5:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction - Savepoints are disabled because Multiple Active 
Result Sets (MARS) is enabled. If 'SaveChanges' fails, then the transaction cannot be automatically 
rolled back to a known clean state. Instead, the transaction should be rolled back by the application 
before retrying 'SaveChanges'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2149338 for more information. 
To identify the code which triggers this warning, call 'ConfigureWarnings(w => 
w.Throw(RelationalEventId.SavepointsDisabledBecauseOfMARS))'.
```

I'm fine with Savepoints being disabled (at least for now), but I'm not so happy with a logmessage for every database save...

Is there a way to tell EF Core to not use this new feature?

Comment: I am wondering what is the reason they decided to throw this warning from SaveChangesAsync simply because a transaction is running? Wouldn't it make more sense to warn if you try to Set a SavePoint or Rollback to a save point?

Comment: I would imagine it's because perhaps under normal circumstances EF uses savepoints when using transactions, but because we have MARS enabled in the connectionstring this feature doesn't work which may be unexpected. Though I would imagine you'd just throw the error once when initializing the DbContext. Not sure why it's on every call.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As it turns out the call to `ConfigureWarnings` as described in the error message can also be used to Ignore the message.

One thing to note however is that contrary to what the warning message says, the `SavepointsDisabledBecauseOfMARS` value is not part of the `RelationalEventId` type. Instead it's part of the `SqlServerEventId` type.

To ignore the warnings, the full code then becomes as follows:

```
ConfigureWarnings(w => 
w.Ignore(SqlServerEventId.SavepointsDisabledBecauseOfMARS))
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Robba's anwer, because you might need to know where to place this method, like me.

You need to override `OnConfiguring` in your `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(SqlServerEventId.SavepointsDisabledBecauseOfMARS));
}
```